# String comparison with list/array of variables

Tags: macros

Is it possible to do a string comparison with a list/array of variables?

Here is my example code, ticking the defined `\currentbox`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
% DEFINE BOX WITH GIVEN NAME
\newcommand\mybox[1]{%
    \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\unexpanded{#1}}{\currentbox}=0 %
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
    {\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\colorbox{teal}{\framebox(18,10){\textbf{\color{white}#1}}}}
    {\framebox(18,10){\textbf{#1}}}%
}
\makeatother

% define current box
\def\currentbox{B}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tcbitemize}[size=fbox,
                       colframe=white,
                       colback=white,
                       raster equal height,
                       raster force size=false,
                       raster equal skip=0pt,
                       raster columns=4]
        \tcbitem[width=0.20\linewidth]
            \mybox{A}
        \tcbitem[width=0.20\linewidth]
            \mybox{B}
        \tcbitem[width=0.20\linewidth]
            \mybox{C}
        \tcbitem[width=0.20\linewidth]
            \mybox{D}
    \end{tcbitemize}%
\end{document}
```

So if `\currentbox` is a list/array containing 'A' and 'B' and it is possible to `strcmp` if it is in a list/array, this would generate:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `expl3`/`xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% DEFINE BOX WITH GIVEN NAME
\NewDocumentCommand\mybox{m}
 {
  \clist_if_in:NnTF \g_api_mybox_labels_clist { #1 }
   {
    \group_begin:
    \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
    \colorbox{teal}{\framebox(18,10){\bfseries\color{white}#1}}
    \group_end:
   }
   {
    \framebox(18,10){\bfseries#1}
   }
 }
\clist_new:N \g_api_mybox_labels_clist
\clist_gset:Nn \g_api_mybox_labels_clist { A , C }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbitemize}[
  size=fbox,
  colframe=white,
  colback=white,
  raster equal height,
  raster force size=false,
  raster equal skip=0pt,
  raster columns=4
]
\tcbitem[width=0.20\linewidth] \mybox{A}

\tcbitem[width=0.20\linewidth] \mybox{B}

\tcbitem[width=0.20\linewidth] \mybox{C}

\tcbitem[width=0.20\linewidth] \mybox{D}
\end{tcbitemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adding an interface for setting the keys is easy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% DEFINE BOX WITH GIVEN NAME
\NewDocumentCommand\mybox{m}
 {
  \clist_if_in:NnTF \g_api_mybox_labels_clist { #1 }
   {
    \group_begin:
    \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
    \colorbox{teal}{\framebox(18,10){\bfseries\color{white}#1}}
    \group_end:
   }
   {
    \framebox(18,10){\bfseries#1}
   }
 }
\clist_new:N \g_api_mybox_labels_clist
\NewDocumentCommand{\setmyboxkeys}{m}
 {
  \clist_gset:Nn \g_api_mybox_labels_clist { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{The list is not set}

\begin{tcbitemize}[
  size=fbox,
  colframe=white,
  colback=white,
  raster equal height,
  raster force size=false,
  raster equal skip=0pt,
  raster columns=4
]
\tcbitem[width=0.20\linewidth] \mybox{A}

\tcbitem[width=0.20\linewidth] \mybox{B}

\tcbitem[width=0.20\linewidth] \mybox{C}

\tcbitem[width=0.20\linewidth] \mybox{D}
\end{tcbitemize}

\section{The list is set}

\setmyboxkeys{A,C}

\begin{tcbitemize}[
  size=fbox,
  colframe=white,
  colback=white,
  raster equal height,
  raster force size=false,
  raster equal skip=0pt,
  raster columns=4
]
\tcbitem[width=0.20\linewidth] \mybox{A}

\tcbitem[width=0.20\linewidth] \mybox{B}

\tcbitem[width=0.20\linewidth] \mybox{C}

\tcbitem[width=0.20\linewidth] \mybox{D}
\end{tcbitemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You might want to add the selection of the keys to the options for `tcbitemize`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% DEFINE BOX WITH GIVEN NAME
\NewDocumentCommand\mybox{m}
 {
  \clist_if_in:NnTF \l_api_mybox_labels_clist { #1 }
   {
    \group_begin:
    \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
    \colorbox{teal}{\framebox(18,10){\bfseries\color{white}#1}}
    \group_end:
   }
   {
    \framebox(18,10){\bfseries#1}
   }
 }
\clist_new:N \l_api_mybox_labels_clist

\tcbset{mybox~keys/.code=\clist_set:Nn \l_api_mybox_labels_clist { #1 }}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{The list is not set}

\begin{tcbitemize}[
  size=fbox,
  colframe=white,
  colback=white,
  raster equal height,
  raster force size=false,
  raster equal skip=0pt,
  raster columns=4
]
\tcbitem[width=0.20\linewidth] \mybox{A}

\tcbitem[width=0.20\linewidth] \mybox{B}

\tcbitem[width=0.20\linewidth] \mybox{C}

\tcbitem[width=0.20\linewidth] \mybox{D}
\end{tcbitemize}

\section{The list is set}

\begin{tcbitemize}[
  mybox keys={A,C},% <---- set the keys
  size=fbox,
  colframe=white,
  colback=white,
  raster equal height,
  raster force size=false,
  raster equal skip=0pt,
  raster columns=4
]
\tcbitem[width=0.20\linewidth] \mybox{A}

\tcbitem[width=0.20\linewidth] \mybox{B}

\tcbitem[width=0.20\linewidth] \mybox{C}

\tcbitem[width=0.20\linewidth] \mybox{D}
\end{tcbitemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excelent! Is it also possible to renew the variables in `\g_api_mybox_labels_clist` in the document?

Comment: @API I'll add an interface later; doing my tour, now. 

Comment: @API I added two ways for setting the keys.

Answer (score 5):

You can use four lines from opmac.tex where `\isinlist` macro is defined:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% from opmac.tex:
\long\def\isinlist#1#2#3{\long\def\tmp##1#2##2\end{\def\tmp{##2}%
   \ifx\tmp\empty \csname iffalse\expandafter\endcsname \else
                  \csname iftrue\expandafter\endcsname \fi}% end of \def\tmp
   \expandafter\tmp#1\endlistsep#2\end
}

% DEFINE BOX WITH GIVEN NAME
\def\mybox#1{%
   \isinlist\currentbox{#1}\iftrue
      \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\colorbox{teal}{\framebox(18,10)
                                             {\textbf{\color{white}#1}}}%
   \else 
      \framebox(18,10){\textbf{#1}}%
   \fi
}

% define current box
\def\currentbox{AC}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tcbitemize}[size=fbox,
                       colframe=white,
                       colback=white,
                       raster equal height,
                       raster force size=false,
                       raster equal skip=0pt,
                       raster columns=4]
        \tcbitem[width=0.20\linewidth]
            \mybox{A}
        \tcbitem[width=0.20\linewidth]
            \mybox{B}
        \tcbitem[width=0.20\linewidth]
            \mybox{C}
        \tcbitem[width=0.20\linewidth]
            \mybox{D}
    \end{tcbitemize}%
\end{document}
```

Note that you need not any more macro package.

Comment: Thanks. I will use `\isinlist\currentbox{"#1"}\iftrue` with `\def\currentbox{"A","C"}` to make it a little bit more robust

Comment: A doubt, since you use `\isinlist\foo{baz}\iftrue` so that it works in nested `\if .. \fi` constructions, why didn't you choose a more readable syntax like `\if\isinlist\foo{baz}YES\else NO\fi`? Is there anything more to that syntax you decided to use?

Comment: @Manuel I don't see any important difference between `\if\ismacro...` and `\ismacro...\iftrue`. The second solution is mine and I use this many years. And I don't mix more approaches in my code. The first solution is (IMHO) more tricky because `\ismacro` needs to be expanded to something like `xx\fi` first. And there is more tricky solution: expand `\ismacro` with `)` separator to `(\fi` first and use: `\if(\ismacro...)`.